# Qt C++ Modifying an object from a list while iterating

Tags: c++, qt

I want to modify the original content of a list object while i'am iterating the list. I've been trying this using 2 ways: first one -> using a for loop -> which is working properly, but i am not sure that is the best option, and the second one using `QMutableListIterator` which is not changing at all the object and i thought that maibe i am not using it corectly. Below there are my 2 implementations.

first one

```
 QString idNumber = getIDNumberFromSelectedRow(id);
 QUuid carId = QUuid(idNumber);
    for(int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        Vehicle& current = cars[i];
        if(carId == current.getVehicleID()){
            addDialog = new AddEditDialog(this);
            addDialog->loadVehicleToEdit(current); // i am loading the data from the object i want to edit
            addDialog->exec();
            if(addDialog->getIsEdited()){ //i'm editing the object
                current = addDialog->getVehicleToAdd(); //i'm saving the modifications
                current.setVehicleId(carId);
            }
        }//the object from the list is now modified
    }
```

second one

```
 QMutableListIterator<Vehicle> iterator(cars);
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Vehicle& current = iterator.next();
        if(carId == current.getVehicleID()){
            addDialog = new AddEditDialog(this);
            addDialog->loadVehicleToEdit(current); //load the object data to modify
            addDialog->exec();
            if(addDialog->getIsEdited()){//edit the object
                current = addDialog->getVehicleToAdd();//save the modifications
                iterator.setValue(current);
            }
        }//the object from the list is not modified at all
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method is really fine, nothing to worry about :-) In Qt, a `QList<T>` is not a linked list like `std::list<T>`, but a container that gives you average constant time for access.

If you still want to use an iterator, do not use `QMutableListIterator<Vehicle>`, but `QList<Vehicle>::iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

[QMutableListIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmutablelistiterator.html) is meant to modify *the list* while you're iterating, for instance inserting/removing items. Then it's not the right tool for your task. Indeed, the documentation states that when you call next(), the iterator points to the *successive* element. Maybe it's this detail that inhibits your changes to appear as expected.

From docs:

> T & QMutableListIterator::next ()
>   Returns a reference to the next item, *and advances the iterator by one position*.